# Using SQL Stored Procedure to encrypt password in SHA2_512 affects 0 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I'm currently working on a database as a student, I'm quite new to SQL and I've been trying to avoid saving passwords in plain text in my DB so I looked through the internet and ended up using

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddUser
    @pAcctID char(8),
    @pLogin NVARCHAR(50), 
    @pPassword NVARCHAR(50), 
    @pLName NVARCHAR(40) = NULL, 
    @pFName NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO AccountInfo(AcctID, LoginName, PasswordHash, LName, FName)
        VALUES(@pAcctID,@pLogin, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword), @pLName, @pFName)

        SET @responseMessage='Success'

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    END CATCH

END

DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)

EXEC uspAddUser
          @pAcctID = '00000001',
          @pLogin = 'Admin',
          @pPassword = '123',
          @pLName = 'Doe',
          @pFName = 'John',
          @responseMessage=@responseMessage OUTPUT

SELECT *
FROM AccountInfo
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It always affects 0 rows. The table remains blank upon the execution of stored procedure. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you looking at the response message?  Perhaps the row already exists in the table, and you are getting a duplicate violation on the insert.

Comment: Put `print @responseMessage` at the end of your sp. Actually, hiding an error is not a good practice. Same as right now - you have no idea what's actually happening there.

Comment: Thank you! When I followed your instruction, I was able to pin-point the fault in the code i'm using. Thank you so much, Ivan and Gordon!